# VHDL code for metal detector

Tags: vhdl

I am working on a metal detector at the moment but can't figure out how to implement it my VHDL code.

```
ENTITY sensor IS

   port ( metaldetector : in std_logic;
          metal         : out std_logic;
        );
END ENTITY sensor;
```

As long as there isn't any metal close to the sensor 'metaldetector' gets pulses on a 6.1kHz frequency. So as long as the 'metaldetector' keeps getting pulses the out port 'metal' should be '0'.

When there is a pulse missing (or multiple pulses) 'metal' should become '1' until the next pulse.

It shouldn't be that hard to make a code that can do that, but i just can't figure it out. Any help would really be great!

Comment: What have you got so far?  For one thing, if you are trying to measure pulses or lack of, you'll need a clock input too.

Comment: I have no clue about how to do this, but you are right about the clk input.

Comment: We're not going to write all the code for you - you'll need to have a go and ask specific questions about specific problems.  What is your first thought on how to find out if there is a pulse missing from a 6.1kHz train for example?

Comment: @Martin I don't expect you to write me the full code, but I don't even have a clue how to start. Could you please explain me how to solve this problem? How to start? I guess we'll need a counter, (that's being reset as soon as there's a new pulse. If the number exceeds a specific value it should generate an metal = '1'?) I don't really know how to start anyway, so any pointer would be appreciated. ;)

Comment: sounds like you *do* have a starting point :)  Write the code for that (maybe in pseudo-code first, then get the VHDL syntax right)

Comment: @Imran As stated and tagged above, VHDL. ;)

Comment: @Sanger - Well never hearing about that language and being a programmer for about 7 years it was not that obvious. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to solve the problem with some help of other students, and a lot of trying.
I'll post our solution down here, hopefully it can be usefull to others. :)

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY sensor IS
     port ( metaldetector : in std_logic;
            clk : in std_logic;
            metal : out std_logic
          );
END ENTITY sensor;

ARCHITECTURE sensorbehav OF sensor IS   
    signal new_count, count: unsigned(20 downto 0);

    begin

    process (clk, metaldetector)
    begin
        if (rising_edge (clk)) then
            if (metaldetector = '1') then
                count <= (others => '0');
            else 
                count <= new_count;
      end if;
    end if;
end process;

process (count)
    begin
        new_count <= count + 1;
end process;

process (count)
    begin
    if (count > 9000) then
        metal <= '1';
    else
        metal <= '0';
    end if;
end process;
END ARCHITECTURE;
```